# Who runs the Android market?

Tags: google-play-store

Does Google run the Android Market?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Google is in charge of the Android Market.

Comment: Okay and with that I have a second question: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2141/what-is-googles-stance-on-keeping-the-android-market-open-to-the-general-public